# Function is undefined even if it's properly defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call openFormPreview(e), which is an async function, from an onclick event. It's defined but console keep giving me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openFormPreview is not defined
```

Here's the code

```js
async function openFormPreview(element) {
  //Do some works
  //Get the element
  console.log(element)
  const dcid = element.getAttribute("data-concern-id");
  //Set data
}

function presentData(doc) {
  //Some other codes
  let a = document.createElement("div");
  a.classList.add("concern-item", "dt-cont-surface");
  a.setAttribute("data-concern-id", doc.id);
  a.setAttribute('onclick', 'openFormPreview(this)');
  //More codes
}
```

```html
<div class="concern-item dt-cont-surface" data-concern-id="jbTFRy0SFxiHRD29NiL3" onclick="openFormPreview(this)"><span class="cl-fname">First Name</span> <span class="cl-cs"><span class="cl-c">12</span> - <span class="cl-s">1A</span></span><span class="cl-cid">jbTFRy0SFxiHRD29NiL3</span></div>
```

They are both in the same js file and linked properly with the HTML file.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. The posted code works as expected and doesn't reproduce the roblem.

Comment: Why not add a click event listener instead of setting the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Try clear cache, or open the script in incognito mode

Comment: For me the snippet works perfectly

Comment: Is the script loaded before the DOM gets created?

Comment: You should use `defer` or `async` attribute. It will maybe solve the problem: the snippet is working in the question.

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky — The error says `openFormPreview` is not defined, not `a`

Comment: @user17517503 — The error says `openFormPreview` is not defined, not `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are setting as the `onclick` attribute is being evaluated in a scope where `openFormPreview` is not defined. (Note that your [mcve] has been made too minimal so does not show the different scopes, and thus doesn't actually reproduce the problem).

Don't use the `onclick` attribute. Use `addEventListener` instead. That will use the current scope.

```
a.addEventListener('click', event => openFormPreview(event.currentTarget));
```